# ¿Por qué se usa "que" en esta frase?

Tags: gramática, subordinadas

> Nuestra misión es reducir el consumo excesivo, al mismo tiempo que queremos hacer el contacto con la naturaleza más accesible a todos.

En la segunda mitad, se dice "al mismo tiempo **que** queremos". ¿Pueden explicarme este uso de la palabra "que"?

Entiendo el sentimiento, pero no veo la forma gramática que esperaba. Lo habría escrito usando la forma de "quiero que". Por ejemplo:

> [...] al mismo tiempo queremos **que** hacer el contacto con la naturaleza **esté** más accesible a todos

Comment: James, si quieres usar el subjuntivo, sería mejor "al mismo tiempo, queremos hacer que el contacto con la naturaleza esté más accesible a todos," o "al mismo tiempo, queremos que el contacto con la naturaleza esté más accesible a todos," o "al mismo tiempo, hacemos que el contacto con la naturaleza esté más accesible a todos."  Aunque se puede usar "hacer el contacto" como sujeto de la cláusula, no es ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu versión no está mal, pero efectivamente hace de la frase dos oraciones, haciendo la locución *al mismo tiempo* sinónima del adverbio *simultáneamente* (y en tal caso, lo normal sería escribirlo como dos oraciones con coma después de *tiempo*). Como prueba de ello, el *queremos* en tu versión solo se podría admitir en el indicativo.

Pero en el ejemplo que citas, la locución *al mismo tiempo que* significa básicamente lo mismo de *mientras que*. En este caso, funciona como conjunción subordinante. Para verificar el estado de la cláusula como subordinada, notamos que se aceptaría tanto subjuntivo como indicativo después del *que* (con interpretaciones algo diferentes, no son intercambiables semánticamente).